# Getting user selected dropdown value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Custom Attribute based validation using   MVC4 in

I can get user entered value in a textbox using following code using propertyinfo[]

```
PropertyInfo textBoxEnteredValue = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("TxtCrossField");
```

But I am not able to get the user selected dropdown value.

1. Is there any code changes need to be done, pls suggest
2. The `object value` is coming as NULL into the `IsValid` method. Any idea why it is so?

**Validation**

```
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {             
       //Working
PropertyInfo textBoxEnteredValue = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("TxtCrossField");

       //How to get the selected item? 
       PropertyInfo selectedDropdownlistvalue = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("DDlList1");                
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class CrossFieldValidation
{        
    public string DDlList1
    { get; set; }

    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is required")]
    [ValueMustbeInRange]
    [Display(Name = "Quantity:")]
    public string TxtCrossField
    { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.CrossFieldValidation
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DdlCrossFields";
}   
<h2>DdlCrossFields</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostValues", "CrossFieldsTxtboxes"))
{   
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TxtCrossField)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.TxtCrossField)
    </div>
  @*@Html.DropDownList("DDlList1",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.itemsforDropdown)*@        
      @Html.DropDownList("ItemsforDrop", ViewBag.ItemsforDrop as SelectList,"Select A state", new {id= "State"})

<input id="PostValues" type="Submit" value="PostValues" />
}
```

would any one pls suggest any ideas on this one...
Many thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The method responsible for receiving the posted form should take your model as argument. As long as your DDL is tied to a property in that model, you will be able to get the selected value like this:

**Controller**

```
[...some attributes...]
public static void MethodInController(YourModelType model)
{
   var selectedValue = model.DropDownListSelectedValue;
}
```

**Model**

```
public class YourModelType
{
   public List<SomeType> DropDownOptions { get; set; }
   [YourValidationAttribute]
   public string DropDownListSelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Validation attribute class**

```
public class YourValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //return based on conditions of "value"
    }
}
```

**View**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropDownListSelectedValue, model.DropDownListOptions)
```

Comment: how can I use this one in custom attribute function

Comment: Forgot that, haha. Updated my answer.

Comment: hmm thanks but in my view i have got two control one is dropdown and other is textbox I want to access both values in custom attribute function , so do i need to put two validation attribute or one ..

Comment: Technically, I think you could apply the same attribute to both properties. Just make sure you apply it to the property containing the selected value of your DDL and not the DDL property it self.

Comment: so, If we are applying same attribute to two different properties how can we know which value is related to which control in side custom attribute validation function...(all values are getting from single 'object value' ...

Comment: I suppose it's like calling the same method/function two times, with different values as parameters. For instance, you would use the same attribute many times in your model to validate "required fields". You put the attributes "on top" of the property you want to validate, that is the connection between the model property and your validation attribute. Does it work for you?

Comment: what I am trying to say is,i need to use two control property values in one validation attribute function....

Comment: Ah I see.. I think I missed the point of your question. This article however, seem to discuss what you are looking for: http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/build-model-aware-custom-validation-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-2/